# RTC - timestamp local files with actual check-in history time

Tags: timestamp, rational-team-concert

RTC "Load" command extracts the repository files to the local workspace - fine.

What I find annoying/problematic is the modification timestamp on the local files is the timestamp of the "Load". I would expect it to be the time of the last check-in.

Is there a SCM/RTC command that will show the latest check-in timestamp for each file - I can then "pipe" this to touch or something.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported, and from the work item [Enhancement 83718](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=83718), this isn't likely to be supported just yet (even though [there is a plan to do so](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=239119)).

The thread "[timestamp problem when checking out](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/34382/timestamp-problem-when-checking-out)" mentions:

> Doing anything else will break date-based build systems like all but the most sophisticated variants of Make.

The thread "[files loaded from source control do not preserve modify date](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/32709/files-loaded-from-source-control-do-not-preserve-modify-date)" details:

This is currently not supported.

> To explore the ramifications of this a bit ... what would you expect to
>   happen if you "suspended" a change set in that workspace?
>
> To be consistent with the rule that "the mod date of a file is its change-set creation date", the mod date on a reverted file would have to be changed to an earlier date. But then date-based build systems (like "`make`") would fail to recompile the reverted files (except for the few build systems like clearmake, which are designed to handle files
>   changing both forward and backward in time).

Comment: Thank you. I take the point about why timestamp support is not there.

Given a file name, what lscm command would give me the timestamp info that might allow me to "touch" the file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
lscm history -m 1 myfile
```

This will give you the identifier of the last changeset suffered by this file.  With this identifier (say XXXX) you can go for:

```
lscm list changesets XXXX
```

This will give you detailed information on the XXXX changeset, including the moment of the change (in localized format; beware of your local installation of scmtools if you intend to automatize this in a script)

Comment: I have tried with RTC 3.0.1, where there is a command 'lastmod'; however, it only works with directories :(

Comment: This commands assume that you have previously logged yourself by typing lscm login -r YourRepository -u YourUser -P YourPassword, etc.